# jquery remove part of url

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Lets say i've got the following url;

```
http://www.domain.com/en-US/assortment/en-US/category/page.aspx?sub=GROUP7
```

As you can see I have two language layers in the url from which I want to remove ONLY the second one. So I expect the url to be like this.

```
http://www.domain.com/en-US/assortment/category/page.aspx?sub=GROUP7
```

Due to technical limitations I don't have any other ways to modify the url. Can this be achieved with jQuery or Javascript? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'your url here...'.replace( '/assortment/en-US/category/', '/assortment/category/');
```

Comment: Sometimes it's so simple. All I had to do was to check a bit more specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the JavaScript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

Well, using the replace function, you can do something ugly like this:

```
var url= "http://www.domain.com/en-US/assortment/en-US/category/page.aspx?sub=GROUP7";

var index = url.lastIndexOf('en-US');  //get last index of language
var substr = url.substr(index);        //get substring of the tail
var newsubstr = substr.replace('en-US','');  //use replace to get rid of second lang
var newurl = url.substr(0,index-1); //first part of the url
var cleanurl = newurl + newsubstr;  //concatenate it
alert(cleanurl);
```

I didn't really take time to make this cleaner - I'll clean it up in a few minutes.

Comment: Tried that already, but doesn't seem to work. It only replaces the first occurance of en-US. And I want to replace the second occurance, not the first one.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are referring a language code, I'll write a javascript code to catch generic language code and replace the duplication.

You can do this easily with regular expressions. check this out

```
url = "http://www.domain.com/en-US/assortment/en-US/category/page.aspx?sub=GROUP7"

//define regular expression to catch /en-US block
// '/' in front of the language code is also catch in this regular expression
rxp = /(\/[\w]{2}(-[\w]{2})?)/

//split by regular expression
ary = url.split(rxp)

//set the fourth eliment to "" the 4th eliment is the second '/en-US'
ary[3] = "" 

//join array with "" to have the prepare the string
url_new = ary.join("")
```

the parameter inside the join method is essential.

This should work on most of the language codes currently in use.